# PIC18f4520 programming error

Tags: pic, c

I am trying to run a program on PIC18F4520 using PicKit3 & MPLAB IDE. But I am getting an error:
PK3Err0040: The target device is not ready for debugging.
Please check your configuration bit settings and program
the device before proceeding.

Whereas when I try to run one of the old program, its running. My new program code which is not running is:

```
#pragma config OSC = HS,FCMEN = OFF,IESO = OFF              // CONFIG1H
#pragma config PWRT = OFF, BOREN = SBORDIS, BORV = 0                       // CONFIG2L
#pragma config WDT= OFF, WDTPS = 32768                                    // CONFIG2H
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF, LPT1OSC = OFF, PBADEN = ON, CCP2MX = PORTC       //CONFIG3H
#pragma config STVREN = ON, LVP = OFF, XINST = OFF                // CONFIG4L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF, CP1 = OFF, CP2 = OFF, CP3 = OFF                   // CONFIG5L
#pragma config CPB = OFF, CPD = OFF                                         // CONFIG5H
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF, WRT1 = OFF, WRT2 = OFF, WRT3 = OFF                // CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRTB = OFF, WRTC = OFF, WRTD = OFF                            // CONFIG6H
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF, EBTR1 = OFF, EBTR2 = OFF, EBTR3 = OFF           // CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTRB = ON                                                  // CONFIG7H


#include "p18f4520.h"
#include "delays.h"


void main(void) 
{ 
TRISA=0b11111111;
TRISB=0b11111111;
TRISC=0b11111111;
TRISD=0b00000000;
TRISE=0x11111111;

while(1)
    {
     Delay10KTCYx(200);
     LATDbits.LATD3=1 ;
     LATDbits.LATD2=1 ;
     LATDbits.LATD1=1 ;
    }

 }
```

Please let me know where the issue is? is it something to do with bootloader?

Comment: You must have noticed that the formatting of your question didn't look good. Please check [this page](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for information about how you can improve formatting. Users will be more inclined to help if a question is readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
#pragma config DEBUG = ON
```

Answer (score 0):

Some PICs require a debug header in order to enter debug mode. Make sure the 18F4250 does not require a special debug header.

Answer (score 0):

I've had cryptic messages like this when programming and debugging PIC18F with PICkit3, enabling "Power target circuit" option normally solves it.  I don't know if it's a PICkit or MPlab oddity, but the option makes the difference between success and failure.

In MPLab, go to `Debugger` menu, then `settings`, choose the `power` tab, and check the `power Target Circuit from PICkit3` check box, click apply and OK.